# UIView to stick at bottom of UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So I have a UIScrollView inside a UIView of a UIViewController in which I added a UIView inside it, and I wanted it to always stick at the bottom regardless of the orientation changes. So I had the following:

[image]

The issue is that when I rotate into landscape, the scroll view content size height is definitely going to be bigger than the frame height, and therefore it scrolls down. However this UIView that I want to stick at the bottom doesn't stick. How do I make it so that it always stick to the bottom regardless of the orientation changes.

When I disabled UIScrollView autoresize subviews, this UIView sticks to the bottom, but the width doesn't adjust when rotated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to adjust frame according to `orientations` see below example -

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
{
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        //set your portrait frame here and also the content size of scrollView
    }
    else
    {
        //set your Landscape frame here and also the content size of scrollView
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try to  use auto-resizing mask in the following manner

```
yourview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

using the coding or in IB add the top, left, bottom, and right margin flexibility.

or otherwise place view as per your requirement in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation method.